# join value in a RETURNING which is not inserted

Tags: postgresql, join, insert

I'm doing an insert from a query which joins two tables, then I want the new ID from the inserted row, and a field from the original row which is not involved in the insert. Is it possible? I get a "column doesn't exist" error.

```
INSERT INTO new_table (x,y) 
select A.x,B.y 
from A 
  join B on A.w = B.z 
RETURNING id,B.z;
```

The `new_table` has a unique constraint on `(x,y)`.

The `new_id` and `B.z` are needed to insert into a second table.

Answer (score 13):

Perhaps there's a better alternative but I can only think of joining back to the 2 tables.

This assumes that `new_table` has a unique constraint on `(x,y)` and that these columns are not nullable:

```
with ins (id, x, y) as
( insert into new_table (x, y) 
  select A.x, B.y 
  from A join B on A.w = B.z 
  returning id, x, y
)
-- insert into another_table (id, z)
select 
    ins.id, B.z        -- whatever columns from the 3 tables
from ins 
  join A on A.x = ins.x 
  join B on B.y = ins.y and A.w = B.z ;
```

Comment: Never would have crossed my mind to use an insert statement as a subquery.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best option is to use nexval on the sequence of the new table.

```
with x as (
select nextval('new_table_id_seq') as new_id, A.x, B.y
from A JOIN  B ON A.w = B.z
),
y as (
    insert into new_table (id, x,y) select new_id, x,y from x
)
select new_id, x,y from x;
```

Comment: I think you want `select new_id, x, y from y;` on your last line there?

Answer (score 2):

I have been facing the same problem.
I have not found a way to work out the problem without inserting into the table an unique identifier so it can returned and used later.

An example that I built up and macthes my own problem was :

Part A : sample data ; basically a list of groups with users, their phone numbers and emails. This list is to be migrated to a set of tables. 
Assumptions : a user belongs to only one group.

```
-- The already existing data 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sourceData;
CREATE TABLE sourceData (
    -- This table holds the data that is to be migrated to groups, users, emails
    gid serial PRIMARY KEY,
    groupName varchar (50) NOT NULL,
    personName varchar (255) ,
    emailAddress varchar(255),
    phone varchar (20) 
);

INSERT INTO sourceData
    (groupName, personName, emailAddress, phone)
    VALUES
    ('Group A','Philippe','phil@psql.org', NULL),
    ('Group A','Philippe',NULL,'0123456789'),
    ('Group A','Francis','francis@gmail.com', NULL),
    ('Group B','Patrick','patrick@kickmyass.com','0147852369'),
    ('Group B','Robert',NULL,'0963852741'),
    ('Group B','Alice', NULL, NULL)
;

-- 

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS groups CASCADE;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users CASCADE;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS emails CASCADE;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS phones CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE groups (
    -- table with names of groups
    gid serial PRIMARY KEY,
    group_name varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE users (
    -- table to join companies with various contact adresses, which may be emails, phone numbers, etc ...
    -- each person may have several of them
    gid serial PRIMARY KEY,
    gid_groups integer NOT NULL,
    personName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fkt2 FOREIGN KEY (gid_groups) REFERENCES groups (gid)
);

CREATE TABLE emails (
    -- table with email adresses
    gid serial PRIMARY KEY,
    gid_users integer NOT NULL,
    email_address varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fkt3 FOREIGN KEY (gid_users) REFERENCES users (gid)
);

CREATE TABLE phones (
    -- table with phone numbers
    gid serial PRIMARY KEY,
    gid_users integer NOT NULL,
    phone_number varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fkt4 FOREIGN KEY (gid_users) REFERENCES users (gid)
);

-- Now we start with the names already inserted
INSERT INTO groups (group_name)
    SELECT DISTINCT groupName FROM sourceData ;
-- we are not even sure in which order they are inserted
```

Part B : migrating the data.

```
-- Insertion of users and their email adresses for those who have some
WITH selectedData  AS 
    (   -- selection of the data that needs to be inserted
        SELECT 
            gp.gid AS gp_gid, sourceD.personName , sourceD.emailAddress
            FROM groups AS gp
            JOIN sourceData AS sourceD
            ON gp.group_name = sourceD.groupName
            WHERE sourceD.emailAddress IS NOT NULL
    ),
insertUsers AS
    (
        INSERT INTO users
            ( gid_groups , personName  )
            SELECT 
                gp_gid , personName
                FROM selectedData
            RETURNING gid_groups AS gp_gid , gid AS user_gid , personName
    )
INSERT INTO emails
    ( gid_users , email_address )
    SELECT 
        insertUsers.user_gid , selectedData.emailAddress
        FROM insertUsers
        JOIN selectedData
        ON insertUsers.personName = selectedData.personName
;

-- Insertion of phone numbers for users who already exist in the database
WITH selectedData  AS 
    (   -- selection of the data that needs to be inserted
        SELECT 
            gp.gid AS gp_gid, sourceD.personName , sourceD.phone
            FROM groups AS gp
            JOIN sourceData AS sourceD
            ON gp.group_name = sourceD.groupName
            WHERE sourceD.phone IS NOT NULL
    )
INSERT INTO phones
    ( gid_users , phone_number  )
    SELECT 
        users.gid , selectedData.phone
        FROM selectedData
        INNER JOIN users -- ensures that only already existing users are selected
        ON selectedData.personName = users.personName
;

-- Insertion of users with their phone numbers for those who have no email address and thus do not exist yet in the database
WITH selectedData  AS 
    (   -- selection of the data that needs to be inserted
        SELECT 
            gp.gid AS gp_gid, sourceD.personName , sourceD.phone
            FROM groups AS gp
            JOIN sourceData AS sourceD
            ON gp.group_name = sourceD.groupName
            WHERE sourceD.phone IS NOT NULL
    ),
insertUsers AS
    (
        INSERT INTO users
            ( gid_groups , personName  )
            SELECT 
                selectedData.gp_gid , selectedData.personName
                FROM selectedData
                LEFT JOIN users
                ON selectedData.personName = users.personName
                WHERE  users.personName IS NULL -- ensures that only users not already in database are inserted
            RETURNING gid_groups AS gp_gid , gid AS user_gid , personName
    )
INSERT INTO phones
    ( gid_users , phone_number )
    SELECT 
        insertUsers.user_gid , selectedData.phone
        FROM insertUsers
        JOIN selectedData
        ON insertUsers.personName = selectedData.personName
;
```